# Why does my Excel VBA code still run after closing my form?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm creating a fairly extensive Excel user form making use of several custom classes I've written. Things currently seem to work as expected, but sometimes when I close the form a process appears to still be running in the background.

I know this because after closing said form, sometimes a CPU core keeps running at full capacity, and when I click on a cell in my spreadsheet the value shown in the formula bar blinks rapidly, as if the spreadsheet were being repeatedly refreshed.

I've tried inserting breaks and debug statements in the Class_Terminate functions of each class (or at least all the big ones), and they all seem to deconstruct neatly. Furthermore, when I rest at a code break, everything halts as expected.

So, what gives? Is there a better way to isolate the problem? How can I find out what's still running after I close my userform?

Comment: What do you see in Task Manager?

Comment: Is it really the Cpu you're checking, or the RAM? Perhaps there is a timer implemented in your workbook, in that case you need to check out the Thisworkbook object. Or are there perhaps constantly updating links to external workbooks (non-VBA)?

Comment: It's the CPU. After closing my form, EXCEL.EXE goes to 25% CPU usage and stays there until I break and stop my code via the VBA coding window. I don't believe there are links to external workbooks, but given the complexity of my project and the different versions I've been working with it's possible--I'll check for that. After repeated trials, my error seems to come only after doing certain save-to-spreadsheet operations, closing the form, and then clicking on another worksheet. I'm not sure if that's what causes it, though, as it's intermittent and random. I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: If there is really VBA running, you can check it by opening the VBA editor and tapping control+break. This breaks up your code.

Comment: Yep, there's VBA running - I have to stop it every time manually in the VBA editor that way. The course of actions that leads to this issue so far: I open my form, close it, and then click on a cell in the worksheet I'm using. When I do that, the actual selected cell is several columns to the left of the cell that I clicked. Only when I switch to another sheet does the CPU go to 25%. Odd.

Comment: Do you close the form or terminate it? Do you have any Functions based on Cell change events and so on, although you might not be doing anything..

Comment: It sounds like there are some sheet events running that are activated when you click a cell / activate sheet. Check perhaps in your sheet objects in your vba editor.

Comment: I click the red X, which calls the UserForm_Terminate function. Also, there isn't any code in the workbook object itself, nor in any of the sheets.

Comment: @slothario do you have the freedom and feasibility to transfer your code to a new workbook? :) I understand it's a lot of work (perhaps) but it could save your time most probably...

Comment: That's a good idea, and I tried that. I then felt less inhibited about commenting all the things, and I found out what was causing my problem--see the answer I just submitted if you're interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after some aggressive commenting and uncommenting, it seems like my error has to do with VBA's destructor functions, Class_Terminate().

I have a "WellReader" class within a "WellCollection" class, so when I terminate my WellCollection class, it destructs WellReader along with it. However, if I have Class_Terminate() defined for both classes, it throws my program into a loop (literally). Simply *defining* the functions causes the error, even if there's no code within them.

(Here's [a related StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631321/vb6-collection-remove-doesnt-fire-class-terminate) that sheds some amount of light on this issue.)

So, while I'm not sure why both destructor functions won't work, for now I'll do without one. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

I entered the same status. In my case I had a form opened. Just closing this, stopped the proces of 'running'.